# How to make Circular audio visualizer in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I want to make a visualizer like this [Circular visualizer](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/79209854/#editor), click the green flag to see the animation.

In my project first I draw a circle, I calculate the points on the circle to draw the visualizer bars, I rotate the view to make the bars feels like circle. I use [StreamingKit](https://github.com/tumtumtum/StreamingKit)    to stream live radio. StreamingKit provides the live audio power in decibels. Then I animate the visualizer bars. But when I rotate the view the height and width changes according to the angle I rotate. But the bounds value not change (I know the frame depends on superViews).

## audioSpectrom Class

```
class audioSpectrom: UIView {
    let animateDuration = 0.15
    let visualizerColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    var barsNumber = 0
    let barWidth = 4 // width of bar
    let radius: CGFloat = 40

    var radians = [CGFloat]()
    var barPoints = [CGPoint]()
    
    private var rectArray = [CustomView]()
    private var waveFormArray = [Int]()
    private var initialBarHeight: CGFloat = 0.0

    private let mainLayer: CALayer = CALayer()
    
    // draw circle
    var midViewX: CGFloat!
    var midViewY: CGFloat!
    var circlePath = UIBezierPath()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupView()
    }
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupView()
    }
    
    private func setupView() {
        self.layer.addSublayer(mainLayer)
        barsNumber = 10
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        mainLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.width, height: frame.height)
        drawVisualizer()
    }
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - Drawing Section
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    func drawVisualizer() {
        midViewX = self.mainLayer.frame.midX
        midViewY = self.mainLayer.frame.midY
        
        // Draw Circle
        let arcCenter = CGPoint(x: midViewX, y: midViewY)
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: arcCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)
        let circleShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        circleShapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        circleShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        circleShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        circleShapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        mainLayer.addSublayer(circleShapeLayer)
        
        // Draw Bars
        rectArray = [CustomView]()
        
        for i in 0..<barsNumber {
            let angle = ((360 / barsNumber) * i) - 90
            let point = calculatePoints(angle: angle, radius: radius)
            let radian = angle.degreesToRadians
            radians.append(radian)
            barPoints.append(point)
            
            let rectangle = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: barPoints[i].x, y: barPoints[i].y, width: CGFloat(barWidth), height: CGFloat(barWidth)))
            
            initialBarHeight = CGFloat(self.barWidth)
            
            rectangle.setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint.zero)
            let rotationAngle = (CGFloat(( 360/barsNumber) * i)).degreesToRadians + 180.degreesToRadians
            rectangle.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)
            
            rectangle.backgroundColor = visualizerColor
            rectangle.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(rectangle.bounds.width / 2)
            rectangle.tag = i
            self.addSubview(rectangle)
            rectArray.append(rectangle)
            
            var values = [5, 10, 15, 10, 5, 1]
            waveFormArray = [Int]()
            var j: Int = 0
            for _ in 0..<barsNumber {
                waveFormArray.append(values[j])
                j += 1
                if j == values.count {
                    j = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - Animation Section
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    func animateAudioVisualizerWithChannel(level0: Float, level1: Float ) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: self.animateDuration, delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
                for i in 0..<self.barsNumber {
                    let channelValue: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
                    
                    let wavePeak: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.waveFormArray[i])))
                    let barView = self.rectArray[i] as? CustomView
                    
                    
                    guard var barFrame = barView?.frame else { return }

                    // calculate the bar height
                    let barH = (self.frame.height / 2 ) - self.radius

                    // scale the value to 40, input value of this func range from 0-60, 60 is low and 0 is high. Then calculate the height by minimise the scaled height from bar height.
                    let scaled0 = (CGFloat(level0) * barH) / 60
                    let scaled1 = (CGFloat(level1) * barH) / 60
                    let calc0 = barH - scaled0
                    let calc1 = barH - scaled1

                    if channelValue == 0 {
                        barFrame.size.height = calc0
                    } else {
                        barFrame.size.height = calc1
                    }
                    
                    if barFrame.size.height < 4 || barFrame.size.height > ((self.frame.size.height / 2) - self.radius) {
                        barFrame.size.height = self.initialBarHeight + CGFloat(wavePeak)
                    }
                    
                    barView?.frame = barFrame
                }
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func calculatePoints(angle: Int, radius: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        let barX = midViewX + cos((angle).degreesToRadians) * radius
        let barY = midViewY + sin((angle).degreesToRadians) * radius
        
        return CGPoint(x: barX, y: barY)
    }
}



extension BinaryInteger {
    var degreesToRadians: CGFloat { return CGFloat(Int(self)) * .pi / 180 }
}

extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self * .pi / 180 }
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}

extension UIView{
    func setAnchorPoint(anchorPoint: CGPoint) {
        
        var newPoint = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width * anchorPoint.x, y: self.bounds.size.height * anchorPoint.y)
        var oldPoint = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width * self.layer.anchorPoint.x, y: self.bounds.size.height * self.layer.anchorPoint.y)
        
        newPoint = newPoint.applying(self.transform)
        oldPoint = oldPoint.applying(self.transform)
        
        var position : CGPoint = self.layer.position
        
        position.x -= oldPoint.x
        position.x += newPoint.x;
        
        position.y -= oldPoint.y;
        position.y += newPoint.y;
        
        self.layer.position = position;
        self.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
    }
}
```

I drag a empty view to storyBoard and give custom class as audioSpectrom.

## ViewController

```
func startAudioVisualizer() {
        visualizerTimer?.invalidate()
        visualizerTimer = nil
        visualizerTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: visualizerAnimationDuration, target: self, selector: #selector(self.visualizerTimerFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    
    @objc func visualizerTimerFunc(_ timer: CADisplayLink) {
        
        let lowResults = self.audioPlayer!.averagePowerInDecibels(forChannel: 0)
        let lowResults1 = self.audioPlayer!.averagePowerInDecibels(forChannel: 1)
        audioSpectrom.animateAudioVisualizerWithChannel(level0: -lowResults, level1: -lowResults1)
    }
```

## OUTPUT

1. Without animation

[image]

2. With animation

[image]

In my observation, the height value and width value of frame changed  when rotates. Means when I give `CGSize(width: 4, height: 4)` to bar, then when I rotate using some angle it changes the size of frame like `CGSize(width: 3.563456, height: 5.67849)` (not sure for the value, it's an assumption).

How to resolve this problem?
Any suggestions or answers will be appreciated.

## Edit

```
func animateAudioVisualizerWithChannel(level0: Float, level1: Float ) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: self.animateDuration, delay: 0, options: .beginFromCurrentState, animations: {
                for i in 0..<self.barsNumber {
                    let channelValue: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))
                    
                    let wavePeak: Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.waveFormArray[i])))
                    var barView = self.rectArray[i] as? CustomView
                    
                    
                    guard let barViewUn = barView else { return }
                    
                    let barH = (self.frame.height / 2 ) - self.radius
                    let scaled0 = (CGFloat(level0) * barH) / 60
                    let scaled1 = (CGFloat(level1) * barH) / 60
                    let calc0 = barH - scaled0
                    let calc1 = barH - scaled1

                    let kSavedTransform = barViewUn.transform
                    barViewUn.transform = .identity
                    
                    if channelValue == 0 {
                        barViewUn.frame.size.height = calc0
                    } else {
                        barViewUn.frame.size.height = calc1
                    }
                    
                    if barViewUn.frame.height < CGFloat(4) || barViewUn.frame.height > ((self.frame.size.height / 2) - self.radius) {
                        barViewUn.frame.size.height = self.initialBarHeight + CGFloat(wavePeak)
                    }
                    barViewUn.transform = kSavedTransform

                    barView = barViewUn
                }
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Output

Run the below code snippet show the output

```html
<a href="https://imgflip.com/gif/227xsa"><img src="https://i.imgflip.com/227xsa.gif" title="made at imgflip.com"/></a>
```

GOT IT!!

[circular-visualizer](https://github.com/Alwin-Lazar/circular-visualizer)

Comment: I think you got messed when you use a mixture of `transform` and `frame`.
What I see here is, you apply transforms to each of your bars initially and you modify their `frame`s as you animate using audio values through CADisplayLink.
I think you should save your transform before applying or changing bar `frame`.
Like this,  
`let kSavedTransform = yourBar.transform;`  
`yourBar.transform = .identity;`  
`// Update your frame`  
`// yourBar.frame = CGRect blah blah`  
`// then reapply the transform`  
`yourBar.transform = kSavedTransform;`  
  
It should be working fine.

Comment: @T.HtooAung Thanks for the reply.  I don't understand where I put this code, is it in initial drawing or animating time?

Comment: Your class `audioSpectrom` has 2 main visualizing functions as I see. `drawVisualizer()` and `animateAudioVisualizerWithChannel (level0:level1:)`. Inside `drawVisualizer()`, you initiated your bars, add bars to superview and applied trigonometric transform. Inside `animateAudioVisualizerWithChannel (level0:level1:)`, you updated your bars` frames according to parameters level0 and level1. So I think , you should update your code inside `animateAudioVisualizerWithChannel (level0:level1:)` at the place where you assign new `CGRect` to your bars.

Comment: @T.HtooAung can I change the height value only, without changing the entire CGRect?

Comment: Yes, you can change your height only if you wish. The thing you should notice is that there should be no transform applied before changing your frame. `frame`, `origin`, `origin.x`, `origin.y`, `size`, `size.width` or `size.height` all triggers setter method of `frame` and as a result you are changing the `CGRect` value of the `frame` all along the way. This is just Swifty trick about setter, getters and you can understand this trick if you come from Objective-C based knowledge.

Comment: @T.HtooAung what wrong I done? I added Edited code and output in question, under the Edit section

Comment: Do not write inside `animateKeyframe`. CADisplayLink is running in 60 fps or 30 fps or whatever and is calling your function in each frame.  It makes a linear animation whether you want to be or not.

Comment: @T.HtooAung Then Where Should I write?

Comment: @T.HtooAung this is my GitHub repository. https://github.com/Alwin-Lazar/circular-visualizer-iOS

Comment: @Alwin: why are you changing frame at all? As I understand you have your views placed in correct position, and rotated, and you want to scale them. So just apply scale transform.  But default anchor point located in the center   , but you change it `layer.anchorPoint`.

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov How to scale the view? Means my views have max height is 40 and I get input values in range of 0...40 for animating the view. With respect this values, how to scale the height of view only?

Comment: @Alwin: same way you are applying rotation. Mind that order of operations matter (scale by Y and then rotate is different to rotate and scale by Y).

Comment: Hey Alwin glad you were able to sort out your problem - just as a heads up, in Swift and ObjC we usually capitalize class names. So `audioSpectrom` would become `AudioSpectromView`. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two (maybe three) issues in your code:

---

***1. `audioSpectrom.layoutSubviews()`***

You create new views in layoutSubviews and add them to the view hierarchy. This is not what you are intened to do, because layoutSubviews is called multiple times and you should use it only for layouting purposes.
As a dirty work-around, I modified the code in the func `drawVisualizer` to only add the bars once:

```
func drawVisualizer() {
    // ... some code here
    // ...
    mainLayer.addSublayer(circleShapeLayer)

    // This will ensure to only add the bars once:
    guard rectArray.count == 0 else { return } // If we already have bars, just return


    // Draw Bars
    rectArray = [CustomView]()

    // ... Rest of the func
}
```

Now, it almost looks good, but there are still some dirt effects with the topmost bar. So you'll have to change

---

***2. `audioSectrom.animateAudioVisualizerWithChannel(level0:level1:)`***

Here, you want to recalculate the frame of the bars. Since they are rotated, the frame also is rotated, and you'd have to apply some mathematical tricks. To avoid this adn make your life more easy, you save the rotated transform, set it to `.identity`, modify the frame, and then restore the original rotated transform. Unfortunately, this causes some dirt effects with rotations of 0 or 2pi, maybe caused by some rounding issues. Never mind, there is a much more simple solution:
**Instead of modifiying the `frame`, you better modify the `bounds`.**

- `frame` is measured in the outer (in your case: rotated) coordinate system
- `bounds` is measured in the inner (non-transformed) coordinate system

So I simply replaced all the `frame`s with `bounds` in the function `animateAudioVisualizerWithChannel` and also removed the saving and restoring of the transformation matrix:

```
func animateAudioVisualizerWithChannel(level0: Float, level1: Float ) {
    // some code before

    guard let barViewUn = barView else { return }

    let barH = (self.bounds.height / 2 ) - self.radius
    let scaled0 = (CGFloat(level0) * barH) / 60
    let scaled1 = (CGFloat(level1) * barH) / 60
    let calc0 = barH - scaled0
    let calc1 = barH - scaled1

    if channelValue == 0 {
        barViewUn.bounds.size.height = calc0
    } else {
        barViewUn.bounds.size.height = calc1
    }

    if barViewUn.bounds.height < CGFloat(4) || barViewUn.bounds.height > ((self.bounds.height / 2) - self.radius) {
        barViewUn.bounds.size.height = self.initialBarHeight + CGFloat(wavePeak)
    }

    barView = barViewUn

    // some code after
}
```

---

***3. Warnings***

By the way, you should get rid of all the warnings in your code. I didn't clean up my answer code to keep it comparable with the orginal code.

For example, in `var barView = self.rectArray[i] as? CustomView` you don't need the conditional cast, because the array already contains `CustomView` objects.
So, all the `barViewUn` stuff is unnecessary.
Much more to find and to clean up.

Comment: Thanks man That's worked. But the animation is slow, not smooth

Comment: I think you'll have to play around with the timings of `self.animateDuration` and `visualizerAnimationDuration`. Possible they somehow need to be more aligned to each other. Also it might be better to use `UIView.animate` instead of `UIView.animateKeyframes`, this looks more crisp.

Answer (score -1):

I've found an opensource example on https://github.com/hhajime/SwiftCircularAudioVisualizer
[image: example]

Let's break it down into its main components:

1. **`NeonEffect.swift`**: This file contains a SwiftUI `ViewModifier` for creating a neon effect.

   - **`NeonEffect`**: A struct that applies a neon-like glow to SwiftUI views. It uses blurring, overlay, and blend modes to create the effect.

```
import SwiftUI

struct NeonEffect: ViewModifier {
    let color: Color
    let radius: CGFloat
    let x: CGFloat
    let y: CGFloat

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .overlay(content
                        .blur(radius: radius)
                        .offset(x: x, y: y)
                        .blendMode(.screen))
            .overlay(content
                        .blur(radius: radius)
                        .offset(x: -x, y: -y)
                        .blendMode(.screen))
            .overlay(color)
            .blendMode(.overlay)
    }
}
```

2. **`AudioProcessing.swift`**: This file defines `AudioProcessor`, a class for processing audio data.

   - **Initialization**: Sets up an audio engine and initializes Fast Fourier Transform (FFT).
   - **Audio Engine Setup**: Loads an audio file and configures the audio player node.
   - **FFT Initialization**: Installs a tap on the mixer node to capture audio data and performs FFT on this data.
   - **FFT Execution**: Transforms audio data into frequency magnitudes using FFT.

```
import AVFoundation
import Accelerate

final class AudioProcessor {
    static let sharedInstance = AudioProcessor()
    
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    private let bufferCapacity = 1024
    
    let audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    var frequencyMagnitudes: [Float] = []
    
    private init() {
        setupAudioEngine()
        initializeFFT()
    }
    
    private func setupAudioEngine() {
        _ = audioEngine.mainMixerNode
        audioEngine.prepare()
        
        try! audioEngine.start()
        let audioFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "music", withExtension: "mp3")!
        let audioFile = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: audioFileURL)
        let audioFormat = audioFile.processingFormat
        
        audioEngine.attach(audioPlayerNode)
        audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: audioFormat)
        audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, at: nil)
    }
    
    private func initializeFFT() {
        let fftConfiguration = vDSP_DFT_zop_CreateSetup(
            nil,
            UInt(bufferCapacity),
            vDSP_DFT_Direction.FORWARD
        )
        
        audioEngine.mainMixerNode.installTap(
            onBus: 0,
            bufferSize: UInt32(bufferCapacity),
            format: nil
        ) { [weak self] buffer, _ in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            let channelDataPointer = buffer.floatChannelData?[0]
            self.frequencyMagnitudes = self.performFFT(data: channelDataPointer!, configuration: fftConfiguration!)
        }
    }
    
    private func performFFT(data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>, configuration: OpaquePointer) -> [Float] {
        let realInput = generateRealInput(from: data)
        var (realOutput, imaginaryOutput) = createInOut()
        
        vDSP_DFT_Execute(configuration, realInput, realInput, &realOutput, &imaginaryOutput)
        
        let magnitudes = computeMagnitudes(realOutput: &realOutput, imaginaryOutput: &imaginaryOutput)
        let normalizedMagnitudes = normalize(magnitudes: magnitudes)
        
        return normalizedMagnitudes
    }
    
    private func generateRealInput(from data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>) -> [Float] {
        var realInput = [Float](repeating: 0, count: bufferCapacity)
        for index in 0 ..< bufferCapacity {
            realInput[index] = data[index]
        }
        return realInput
    }
    
    private func createInOut() -> (real: [Float], imaginary: [Float]) {
        let realOutput = [Float](repeating: 0, count: bufferCapacity)
        let imaginaryOutput = [Float](repeating: 0, count: bufferCapacity)
        return (realOutput, imaginaryOutput)
    }
    
    private func computeMagnitudes(realOutput: inout [Float], imaginaryOutput: inout [Float]) -> [Float] {
        var magnitudes = [Float](repeating: 0, count: Constants.numberOfBars)
        
        realOutput.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { realBufferPointer in
            imaginaryOutput.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { imaginaryBufferPointer in
                var complex = DSPSplitComplex(realp: realBufferPointer.baseAddress!, imagp: imaginaryBufferPointer.baseAddress!)
                vDSP_zvabs(&complex, 1, &magnitudes, 1, UInt(Constants.numberOfBars))
            }
        }

        return magnitudes
    }

    private func normalize(magnitudes: [Float]) -> [Float] {
        var normalizedMagnitudes = [Float](repeating: 0.0, count: Constants.numberOfBars)
        var scalingFactor = Float(1)
        vDSP_vsmul(magnitudes, 1, &scalingFactor, &normalizedMagnitudes, 1, UInt(Constants.numberOfBars))
        return normalizedMagnitudes
    }
}
```

3. **`CircularAudioVisializer.swift`**: This SwiftUI view displays the audio visualization.

   - **Constants**: Defines parameters like the number of bars and intensity factors.
   - **View Setup**: Uses a timer to refresh audio data and displays it as bars in a circular layout.
   - **Audio Playback Control**: Includes a button to play or pause the audio, and updates the visualization accordingly.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Constants {
    static let numberOfBars: Int = 32
    static let intensityFactor: Float = 2
    static let intensityThreshold: Float = 100
}

struct CircularAudioVisualizer: View {
    @State private var isPlayingAudio = false
    @State private var audioData: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0, count: Constants.numberOfBars)
    private let audioProcessor = AudioProcessor.sharedInstance
    private let updateTimer = Timer.publish(every: 0.05, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    let innerRadius: CGFloat = 80
    let maxBarLength: CGFloat = 150

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< Constants.numberOfBars) { index in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4)
                        .fill(
                            Color(
                                hue: 0.5 - Double((audioData[index] / Constants.intensityThreshold) / 5),
                                saturation: 1,
                                brightness: 1,
                                opacity: 0.7
                            )
                        )
                        .frame(width: 4, height: min(CGFloat(audioData[index] * Constants.intensityFactor), maxBarLength))
                        .modifier(NeonEffect(color: Color.white.opacity(0.75), radius: 4, x: 1, y: 1))
                        .offset(x: 0, y: -innerRadius - min(CGFloat(audioData[index] * Constants.intensityFactor / 2), maxBarLength / 2))
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(index) / Double(Constants.numberOfBars) * 360))
                }

                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.black)
                    .frame(width: 2 * innerRadius, height: 2 * innerRadius)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print("tapped")
                    }
            }
            .frame(width: 2 * (innerRadius + CGFloat(Constants.intensityThreshold * Constants.intensityFactor)), height: 2 * (innerRadius + CGFloat(Constants.intensityThreshold * Constants.intensityFactor)))

            Button(action: audioPlaybackButtonTapped) {
                Image(systemName: "\(isPlayingAudio ? "pause" : "play").circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        }
        .onReceive(updateTimer, perform: refreshAudioData)
    }

    func refreshAudioData(_: Date) {
        if isPlayingAudio {
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: 0.08)) {
                audioData = audioProcessor.frequencyMagnitudes.map {
                    min($0, Constants.intensityThreshold)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func audioPlaybackButtonTapped() {
        if isPlayingAudio {
            audioProcessor.audioPlayerNode.pause()
        } else {
            audioProcessor.audioPlayerNode.play()
        }
        isPlayingAudio.toggle()
    }
}
```

Each part contributes to creating a visually appealing and functional audio visualizer. The `AudioProcessor` class is crucial for analyzing audio data, `NeonEffect` enhances the visual presentation, and `CircularAudioVisualizer` integrates these components into a user interface.